# Connect Customers With Recurring Profiles to MailChimp

Tags: magento-1.9, api, recurring, mailchimp

Site Info:
Meal prep company, running a site on Magento 1.9.3, the site was developed by a company in India, I work with these guys on some other projects as I'm not really familiar with Magento, but when they told me their issue I offered to take a look.

Their customers are all on subscription-based plans, they use Magento recurring profiles to manage their customers. When looking at the admin area or in the db tables you can see the customers stored in recurring profiles are not stored as customers in Magento, they only exist under recurring profiles.

The issue is we have tried to use to EZbizMarts MailChimp for Magento extension, but the extension is looking for customers in the customer's table but they're in another table. Another issue is all of the recurring profile's info is stored as SQL type blob. So everything from name to address to email is stored in a blob, not broken down into their own rows.

Goal: Either modify the ezbizmarts extension to look at the customers in recurring profiles or write something that would connect without the extension using the MailChimp API. Due to the custom nature of their store, the way products are set up, I think option 2 is better because the extension looks for things that do not exist.

We want to pass the users to MailChimp, and as their status (active, suspended, canceled) changes we want mail chimp to send automated emails. Ideally, we would also be able to send MailChimp the plan that the customer purchases (5, 10 or 14 meals) so we can send upsells etc.

The issue... I'm pretty lost, Magento to me seems a bit overcomplicated in terms of file structure, but I'm pretty new to PHP. What I think I need to do is write php that will retrieve the DB table the information is stored in, put it in an array, then connect to the MailChimp API to send the users that are retrieved from the array, their status, and the product ordered.

Am I on the right track? Another issue is there seems to be very little recurring profiles documentation.

Thanks in advance!